# SQL Query, GROUP/COUNT issue with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I've got a data set composed primarily of dates, IDs, and addresses, that looks a bit like this:

```
datadate   id      address
20150801    Bob     123
20150801    Bob     123
20150801    Dan     345
20150801    Dan     456
20150801    Dan     567
20150801    George  234
20150801    Jim     123
20150801    Jim     123
20150801    John    678
20150801    John    123
20150802    Tom     123
20150802    Tom     234
20150802    Tom     345
```

My goal is to write a query which identifies any IDs which are associated with multiple distinct addresses for a specific date (or date range).  I want the query results to give me the name and distinct addresses.  So, for this data set, the results I'd like to see would look like this, for date 8/1/2015:

```
datadate   id      address
20150801    Dan     345
20150801    Dan     456
20150801    Dan     567
20150801    John    678
20150801    John    123
```

The query I've worked up so far is this, but it's not really working for me:

```
SELECT a.[datadate], a.[id], a.[address], b.[count1]
FROM table1 AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT [id], COUNT([address]) as [count1]   FROM table1   GROUP BY [id]   having count1 > 1   )  AS b ON a.[id]=b.[id]
WHERE a.[datadate] = '20150801'
ORDER BY a.[id], a.[address];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modifying your existing query a little bit, you can change your having to `count(distinct address)` and then joining back to the table to get your address values like this:

```
SELECT t.datadate
      ,t.id
      ,t1.address
FROM (
    SELECT datadate
        ,id
        ,count(DISTINCT address) address
    FROM test
    WHERE datadate = '20150801'
    GROUP BY datadate,id
    HAVING count(DISTINCT address) > 1
    ) t
INNER JOIN test t1 ON t.datadate = t1.datadate
    AND t.id = t1.id;
```

I tested this on `SQL Server`, but should be similar in `MS-Access` as well.

[<kbd>SQL Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f8479/7/0)

Comment: I just tested this one out and it works very well for me too.  It didn't work in `MS-Access` (due to the `DISTINCT` operator), but it worked perfectly in `Impala` (which is where my larger data table is anyway).  Thanks!

Comment: @Psychonaut418 Awesome! Yeah I think the syntax is a bit different for `MS-Acess`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I just read your question again and it appears you want all duplicates. In which case I would use `exists` to see if another row with the same id but a different address exists.

```
select * from mytable t1
where datadate = '20150801'
and exists (
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.id = t1.id
    and t2.address <> t1.address
    and t2.datadate = t1.datadate
)
```

Comment: I prefer `where min(address) <> max(address)` for performance reasons and the fact that MS Access doesn't support `count(distinct)`.

Comment: The issue with grouping by id is that this query won't display the different entries in the address field.

Comment: @FuzzyTree that works perfectly!  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I think I understand everything that's going on in this query, except for the `SELECT 1` line.  What's going on there?  It works, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Psychonaut418 You could actually select anything, some people like to `select *` others select the id. When a query is inside an `exists` clause it doesn't matter what's being selected because you just want to know if a row exists and are not interested in the values.

Comment: @FuzzyTree That makes sense now.  Thanks again for the help and explanation!